# URLs redirection and masking via .htaccess (only subpages without root domain)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've tried many things to solve this and none of them worked the way I need and it's driving me crazy...

I have domainA.com and domainB.com. On domainA.com I have a frontend (just one page website) and on domainB.com I have a backend. domainB.com is an IP address. So, I want to show the backend with pretty URLs and I want to use domainA.com. So, if someone goes to domainA.com/randompagename it should show the content from domainB.com/randompagename, but the URL should stay domainA.com/randompagename.

I've been able to accomplish this with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domainB.com/$1 [P]
```

But it also redirects the root domain and domainA.com shows the content from domainB.com which I don't want to happen.

I want domainA.com to show the content from domainA.com and domainA.com/anypage to show content from domainB.com/anypage

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try your rules this way and see how that works out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainA.com
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://domainB.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: didn't work, when I open the root domain it shows page not found